# Methods to drive an ultrasound transducer

Tags: ultrasound, power-amplifier

I am purchasing an ultrasound transducer with these specifications [image]

I have been looking to use this transducer to achieve focal pressure of .6Mpa or less and have been searching for the best way to drive it.  I have been struggling to know what would be an appropriate RF amplifier for this application that isn't very expensive.  However I have also seen devices called RF signal generators would one of these devices be adequate to drive an ultrasound transducer like this.  This is my first dive into electronics equipment any help is appreciated.

Comment: What power do you need to drive into it? This might also be specified as a voltage or current.

Comment: The manufacturer has said that they use a 15Vpp sine wave and that something around there should be able to get the target .6Mpa focal pressures

Comment: Power needs to be known. Voltage alone does not suffice.